# Detect file changes in Spring Integration

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

Use case: I want to listen to a file directory, and every time someone makes a change on the file, I want it to start a process.

This is my configuration so far:

```
<int-file:inbound-channel-adapter directory="${dir}" auto-startup="${auto.startup}" prevent-duplicates="true" filter="inputfilefilter" channel=rulesChannel">
    <int:poller fixed-delay="${delay}" />
</int-file:inbound-channel-adapter>
```

where inputFileFilteris a custom bean and rulesChannel is the processing later.

The inputFileFilter takes an array of files and returns a list of files, sorted on file ending. This seems to be pulling endlessly, and the "prevent-duplicates"-check is done after the filter (i.e. the file is added, but it seems like it's not sent to the rulesChannel).

Anyway, my problem is that I need this whole thing to pick up *file changes*, not new files. Mainly, it's a configuration file that is being changed every now and then, and I need to update it to keep it in sync.

Yes, this is a horrible solution all over, but it's not really my call, and it seems I have no choice.

Any good ideas?

edit: I've played a bit around with http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/files.html#_watchservicedirectoryscanner to see if I could perhaps copy the class and use it with StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_MODIFY but it doesnt seem to help.

Basically, If I had a good way to just "start a thread and keep it running", I would be fine as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I had to do was implement my own DefaultDirectoryScanner.

It registers a watcher at startup, and checks the watcher when it receives a request from the inbound-channel-adapter through listEligibleItems(..)

To be able to handle two separate file directories, I simply added two different watchers and two different file pollers. This is mainly to ensure readability in the code and to avoid hacking my way around the "directory"-part of the inbound-channel-adapter.